# Invalid route options ( ) "value" must be an object - Hapi.js/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, hapi

I'm creating a REST-API with Hapi and Node. I'm trying to put my routes in separate files following this guys ([How to store routes in separate files when using Hapi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766623/how-to-store-routes-in-separate-files-when-using-hapi)) approach. But with the Code bellow I get this error: `Invalid route options ( ) "value" must be an object`.

I have a `user.js` with my routes:

```js
import { UserController } from "../../controllers/user.js";

const baseUrl = '/api/v1';
const userController = new UserController();

export class UserRoutes {

    user() {
        return [
            {
                method: 'GET',
                path: baseUrl + '/users',
                config: {
                    handler: (request, response) => {
                        return userController.find(request, response);
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                method: 'GET',
                path: baseUrl + '/user/{user_id}',
                config: {
                    handler: UserController.findById
                }
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

and `index.js` in the same folder, which should merge the other route files (I currently don't have) into one array of routes:

```js
import { UserRoutes } from './user.js';

export class Routes {
    getRoutes() {
        return [].concat(UserRoutes);
    }
}
```

and use it in the root `index.js` like so:

```js
import {Routes} from './src/routes/v1/index.js';

let routes = new Routes();
server.route(routes.getRoutes());
```

Am I doing something wrong? I also tried CommonJS as in the other Stack Overflow thread I mentioned above - but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally found what the error was causing. I wanted the Class UserRoutes in `return [].concat(UserRoutes);` to return the value that the Method inside should return... *insert facepalm here*. First I had to instaciate the class and then call the method.. as allways...

`routes/index.js`

```js
    getRoutes() {
        let userRoutes = new UserRoutes();

        return [].concat(userRoutes.user());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error because I had a test file for the post route where I forgot to add spec in file name, so make sure your files naming's are correct

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).